# Wait for user to update question before voting

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, new-users

I was reviewing questions with close votes in StackOverflow and for some of the questions, the question was voted to be closed because the user had not updated the question with enough details on the problem they are facing, or proper code examples.

For new users, I feel it to be discouraging for the user when the question gets closed soon before the user can update more information on the question. Right after the question is posted, some user or the other immediately posts a link for rules to be followed when posting a question. So shouldn't we wait for some time before we allow that question to be voted for closure?

Can we consider something about this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

> #### Wait for user to update question before voting

No, how should we make OPs aware otherwise, that there's something wrong with their question, and it doesn't meet the site's policies?

Comments asking for clarification might be given (and often enough done), but are often received by inexperienced OPs as either irrelevant, snarky, or even unfriendly / rude.
Also having an extensive *help center* at each site, it seems to be irrational to waste everyone's time writing comments, and guide the OP through how to ask a proper question.

> the question was voted to be closed because the user had not updated the question with enough details on the problem they are facing, or proper code examples.

That's the mere purpose of close voting (putting [on hold]). To make the OP aware what they've been missing, and force them to update and improve their question, to be able receiving an answer at all.

> For new users, I feel it to be discouraging for the user when the question gets closed soon **before the user can update** more information on the question.

Usually they're given enough time to do that, before their question will be finally deleted.
Questions may be reopened after the OP updated, and even will be bumped up in the home page after they did so.

> So shouldn't we wait for some time before we allow that question to be voted for closure?

No, the sooner we get rid of VLQ questions, the better for the overall quality of the Q&A repository.